# Исключение при XML Deserialize

Tags: c#, xml

Как бросить исключение при десериализации если свойство в xml не будет найдено?

Например у меня был класс Persons и я его успешно сериализовал:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Persons")]
public class Persons
{
    [XmlArray(nameof(Names)), XmlArrayItem(typeof(string), ElementName = "Name")]
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Persons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Names>
    <Name>Ivan</Name>
    <Name>Alena</Name>
  </Names>
</Persons>
```

Затем мне понадобилось Names в классе Persons изменить на FullNames:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Persons")]
public class Persons
{
    [XmlArray(nameof(FullNames)), XmlArrayItem(typeof(string), ElementName = "Name")]
    public List<string> FullNames { get; set; }
}
```

Как можно получить исключение при десериализации в случае когда FullNames не будет найдено в xml (предварительно xml не менялся, в нем все тот же старый Names):

```
try
{    
    using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    person = (Persons)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Обработка исключения
}
```

Нужно чтобы обновить xml, создать новую по умолчанию с новым именем свойства. Сейчас я просто получаю пустой список FullNames.

Comment: Так может лучше использовать `XmlArray("Names")`, чтобы файлы старого формата читались (и новые писались в том же самом формате)? Атрибуты как бы для этого и предназначены, чтобы можно было менять модель независимо от формата.

Comment: К сожалению надо именно так как описано)

Comment: Покажите XML, который имеется сейчас, класс, который имеется сейчас и желаемый результат.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov обновил

Answer (score 1):

**Для XML ответ не актуален, только для JSON.**
Но вдруг кому пригодится.

В `.NET 7` можно использовать атрибут `[JsonRequired]`:

```cs
[JsonRequired]
public List<string> FullNames { get; set; }
```

Либо модификатор `required` из `C# 11`:

```cs
public required List<string> FullNames { get; set; }
```

[Документация.](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно в xml.

Comment: @Gardes Ай. Да, что-то я невнимательно посмотрел )

Answer (score 1):

Автор ввёл всех (во всяком случае, меня) в заблуждение фразой

> Как бросить исключение при десериализации если свойство в xml не будет найдено?

и заключив код десериализации в блок `try-catch`.

Что означает исключение? Что произошло нечто из ряда вон выходящее и нужно откзаться от уже считанных данных. И в блоке `catch` заполнить класс дефолтными значениями.
В такой трактовке проблема решается следующим образом.

У сериализатора есть события. Можно на них подписаться и в событии выбросить исключение.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Persons));
serializer.UnknownElement += Serializer_UnknownElement;
Persons person;
try
{
    using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    person = (Persons)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    person = new Persons { FullNames = new List<string> { "A", "B" } };
}

void Serializer_UnknownElement(object? sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Здесь в обработчике исключения класс `Persons` создаётся со значениями по умолчанию.

---

Но, насколько я понял, нужно не прерывать процесс десериализации, а прочитать данные из XML со старыми названиями.
Это можно сделать множеством способов.

1. Десериализуем XML в класс `PersonsDTO`, который имеет свойство `Names`. После чего мапим DTO на нужный объект `Persons`. Собственно, это стандартный современный способ с использованием промежуточного типа для передачи данных из слоя в слой.
2. Опять используем событие и в нём вручную парсим вложенные элементы XML:

```
void Serializer_UnknownElement(object? sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Element.Name == "Names")
    {
        var persons = (Persons)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
        var values = e.Element.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Select(x => x.InnerText);
        persons.FullNames.AddRange(values);
    }
}
```

В данном конкретном случае это просто, потому что нам нужно разобрать всего один уровень вложенности с простым типом.
Но в общем случае это может быть трудоёмко. Мы же для того и взяли десериализатор, чтобы избежать ручного парсинга?

3. Кастомный XmlReader. Мой любимый способ.
   Пишем класс-читатель, который на лету подменяет одно название элемента на другое. В нашем случае `Names` меняется на `FullNames`.

```
class NamesXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public NamesXmlReader(string url) : base(url) { }

    public override string LocalName
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.LocalName == "Names")
                return "FullNames";
            return base.LocalName;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее, соответственно, используем его:

```
using var reader = new NamesXmlReader(path);
person = (Persons)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Однако, нужно быть осторожным, т. к. в данном случае **все** элементы `Names` будут переименованы. А в сложном XML вполне могут быть совпадающие имена на разных уровня вложенности и в разных неймспейсах. В таком случае нужно вводить дополнительные проверки.

4. Можно реализовать интерфейс `IXmlSerializable` у нашего типа `Persons`. Но это получается, по сути, ручной парсинг.
5. Также можно с помощью LINQ2XML прочитать XML, что тоже является ручным разбором и отказом от автоматической десериализации. Хотя во многих случаях это реально проще, чем добиться от `XmlSerializer'а` желаемого поведения.

Comment: Это для случая когда встречается элемент не описанный в классе. В моем случае элемент описан, но в файле его нет.

Comment: @Gardes - ничего не понимаю... Подписка на событие в точности решает проблему, описанную в вопросе.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementeventargs?view=netframework-4.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разобраться с этим вопросом, нужно понимать общую логику. Во-первых, XML это не совсем то же самое, что JSON. Во-вторых, парсер XML справедливо считает, что нужный класс просто не найден (есть другой класс).

Поэтому, чтение данных не поможет. Нужно извлечь из XML схему данных и проверить, есть ли в ней элемент "FullNames". Возможно, это делается [так](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset), [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584080/schema-validation-xml).